# ubuntu eclipse mars e(fx)clipse error on startup

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-mars, efxclipse

I installed e(fx)clipse over my existing Eclipse Mars installation using the update sites given here: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.efxclipse/downloads
The installation worked fine, e(fx)clipse also seems to be loaded (load screen on startup changed). But when starting Eclipse, I get the following error displayed after selecting the workspace: "An error has occured. See the log file [...]".

Can anybody help me with this? I would add the log file, but I'm new here and I don't know how to upload.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your log file is in `<workspace location>/.metadata/.log`. One other thing to double check is that you are using Java 8.

Comment: Yes, I know where the log file is located, I just don't know how to upload it here. I looked there, but it's not very useful in my opinion. The command    java -version    says Java 8 is installed

Comment: For future reference, you can just put the log file (pertinent parts, although it sounds like there weren't any in this case) in the message. You probably want to embed it as code (indent by 4+ spaces) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved the problem by myself. I don't know exactly what the problem was, but it seems as if workspace settings were a problem. I deleted the whole workspace directory so it was recreated, and that method worked out fine. I also installed a more recent version of the jdk1.8, but I don't think that was a problem since I also got the error after installation and before I deleted the workspace directory.